# updating multiple tables in MySQL fail

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guy i have some in formation with multiple rows in tables A,B and i want to update table C with this information's but i don't understand why i have fail with updating table c?

```
//Table A, B

$result = $db->sql_query("SELECT f.*, p.member_id, p.name
FROM ipb_profile_friends f, ipb_members p
WHERE f.friends_member_id = p.member_id");

while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) 
{
    //Table C

    $update = $df->sql_query('UPDATE panel_friends 
                SET id="'.$row['friends_id'].'",
                friends_member_id="'.$row['friends_member_id'].'",
                friends_member_name="'.$row['name'].'",
                friends_friend_id="'.$row['friends_friend_id'].'",
                friends_friend_name="",
                friends_approved="1",
                friends_added="'.$row['friends_added'].'",
                is_ignored="1"');
    $affected_rows = $df->sql_affectedrows($update);

    if ($affected_rows > 0) 
    {   
        echo $row['name'] . "</br>";
    } else {
        echo "fail";
    }
}
```

Comment: How do other people do it?

Comment: first of all replace `echo 'fail';` to `echo 'Invalid query: '.$df->mysql_error();` to see error message.

Comment: Your `update` has no `where` clause, I would fix that first (unless you intend to update every record in `panel_friends`).

Comment: I see `$db` used to query a database and `$df` as well. Should they be the same variable? Also, thank you, @chris85, for formatting the post!

Comment: Do you mean UPDATE or INSERT?

Comment: After you do the `->query()` and before doing the `affectedrows`  test `$update` to see if the update actually worked, and if not output an error `if ($update === false) { echo $db->error; exit; }`

Comment: @Alex `mysql_error()` ???? I do hope both the OP and you are not using the `mysql_` API

Comment: @RiggsFolly, it's just advice to inspect actual database error. `$df->mysql_error` not related to any database API it's just object method.

Comment: Ty all guys i must do insert in fist time then update